# Distinct value from Array of Object in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

I am trying to get the distinct value of array in Object. 
I find similar post but It cant solve me issue.

**Output**

[image]

In Airline there might be 1 or multiple values  ( which might be repeated ) from API.
How can I count the distinct value of **Airline**, **Flight**, **Agent**, **Commodity_level_1** and **Commodity_level_2**

**Update**

[image]

**Code**

```
    Array.forEach(element => {
          let al = element.selectedData.airline.filter(
            (v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i
          );
          console.log(al, " in the loop");
        });
```

**Result**

- "AirArabia"
- "Emirates"
- "Turkish"

Comment: The below link is what you are looking for i suppose, You need to call the same method for all the fields, be it airlines, Flight, Agent etc. Let me know if it helps, or you can share a sample code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: `array.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)` as an answer in the topic @CarlosMartins  said